# try to load a html with script on it into another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, load

thank for your time it's my first post here :)

so i have a script who work well, here my page1.html simplified :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var lang = "en";
    $(function(){ 
        $("#morelink").load("page2.html");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="morelink"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here my page2.html simplified, is an add into my page 1 :

```
<div>       
    <a href="model_1_'+lang+'.html">
        <img src="image1.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="model_2_'+lang+'.html">
        <img src="image2.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="model_3_'+lang+'.html">
        <img src="image3.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

the loading work well, but this don't work, because when i click on a link should give me an link with:

```
 model_3_en.html
```

but he give me :

```
 model_3_'+lang+'.html
```

why the   *var lang = "en"* don't work ?

Comment: because its not defined on `page2.html`

Comment: Server knows nothing about `var lang = "en";`

Comment: @roullie But page2.html is getting loaded into a div of main page, where we can access the `lan` variable

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your anchor's `href` attribute dynamically after the loading process of new page content.

Try to change your `page2.html` like below,

```
<div>       
    <a data-link="model_1_">
        <img src="image1.png" />
    </a>
    <a data-link="model_2_">
        <img src="image2.png" />
    </a>
    <a data-link="model_3_">
        <img src="image3.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

And your script like below,

```
var lang = "en";
$(function(){ 
  $("#morelink").load("page2.html",function(){
       $("#morelink a[data-link]").attr("href", function(){
          return $(this).data("link") + lang + ".html";
       });
  });
});
```